# AOP annotations for private methods

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, aspectj

Is there any way to make annotations for AOP work with private methods?
Here's a sample class

```
public class Foo {
  @AvgTimeCounted(MY_SPECIAL_COUNTER_ENUM)
  private void doSomething() {
     ...
  }
}
```

And here is an Aspect for this annotation

```
@Aspect
public class ShardRevertAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(avgTimeCounted)")
    public Object countTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, AvgTimeCounted avgTimeCounted) throws Throwable {
        AverageTimeMetric metricType = avgTimeCounted.value();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

        MetricsContextManager.addToMetric(metricType, (double) System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        return result;
    }
}
```

So I just put the result of time to some context.

With AspectJ and Spring it doesn't work with private methods.

Are there any alternatives for me to make it work? I really need this kind of annotation.

Comment: Spring AOP is, by default, proxy based and will therefor only work on non-final `public` and `protected` methods. If you want something else you will need to use fullblown AspectJ with either load time or compile time weaving.

Comment: @M.Deinum will this weaving work within Spring application with Spring AOP?

Comment: Yes it will work with anycode, but will complicate either your build or your startup procedure.

Comment: I don't want to write an answer and steal M. Deinum's reputation, his answer is correct and he should write one. I just want to provide the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) link. Beware: As of today there is a bug in the documentation (current=5.2.2) which messes up indexing and formatting. I hope it will be fixed soon, so here is the [5.2.1 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in which is still looks okay.

Comment: @kriegaex I did everything according this instruction and it doesn't work...

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit fuzzy. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful, ideally with Maven build and on GitHub. Then the community here could see what your project looks like.